# Featured Images does not show in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I have the following custom post-type:

```
<?php

function university_post_types() {

  // Professor Post Type
  register_post_type('professor', array(
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
    'public' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Professors',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Professor',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Professor',
      'all_items' => 'All Professors',
      'singular_name' => 'Professor'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more'
  ));

}

add_action('init', 'university_post_types');
```

Within my `functions.php` file I am registering my theme support the following:

```
function university_features() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  add_image_size('professorLandscape', 400, 260, true);
  add_image_size('professorPortrait', 480, 650, true);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'university_features');
```

My problem is that no, `featured-image` box is showing within my custom post type.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Do you mean that you don't see the option to add a featured image in the editor when editing a post of that post type?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try specifying the post type when you declare the support

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post','professor' ) );
```